# Make divs same width with pure css

Tags: html, css

Is there a pure CSS way to create a div that matches another's div width? There is no parent div.

```css
.green-div-1 {
    background-color: #00ba00;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
}

.blue-div-1 {
    background-color: #8888FF;
    max-width: 90%;
    float: left;
}

.green-div-2 {
    background-color: #00ba00;
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
}

.blue-div-2 {
    background-color: #8888FF;
    max-width: 90%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-div-1">
    <div class="blue-div-1">
        <label>long text long text long text long text long text long text </label>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="green-div-2">
    <div class="blue-div-2">
        <label>short text</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6kgjnL15/

Comment: I am not fully aware on what your problem is, isnt the image your showing and the fiddle both returning equal sized divs?

Comment: How will you try to relate the first div with second div when there is no constraint i.e a parent div?

Comment: Which ones do you want to match, the blue inners? Just give them with 100%. Or the blue inners, matched to the greatest width?

Comment: Exactly. I want the blue inners, matched to the greatest width.

Comment: You can't make a second div as wide as the first without specifying the width anywhere. Also `float` means the element "shrink-wraps" around its content, I'm pretty sure you don't want `float`.

Comment: There is no way you can without both divs having a common parent element with pure CSS. And you could have with use of javascript but that's out of the option.

Comment: No, no way to do it with just css, however is so simple with a bit of javascript. in case you are interested: https://jsfiddle.net/L2h7u81a/

Comment: Or even better, if you don't know which one is goign to have more text: https://jsfiddle.net/qxnnawy2/

Comment: @SvSv See my modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need of `float: left;` as they both are in separate div's

try removing the `float: left` from

```
.blue-div-1{
  background-color:#8888FF; max-width:90%;
}

.blue-div-2{
  background-color:#8888FF; max-width:90%;
}
```

here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/s8ufxu1m/2/

Also this will help to understand more CSS Box Model: https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for. but changing max-width to just width then setting that at 100% makes both blue divs identical.

```
  .blue-div-1{
  background-color:#8888FF; width:100%; float:left;
}  

.blue-div-2{
  background-color:#8888FF; width:100%; float:left;
}
```

Comment: I don't think setting a fixed width on both elements is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudo elements, you can get the desired result. You can find the code below. However, I highly recommend using `JavaScript` for your problem, as you can achieve a much more stable and flexible solution.

**In case the background-color is not important, try this:**

```css
.green-div-1{
  background-color:#00ba00; width:500px;height:20px;
}
.blue-div-1{
  max-width:90%; float:left;
}

.green-div-2{
  background-color:#00ba00; width:500px;height:20px;
}
.blue-div-1::after {
  content:"short text";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-div-1">
    <div class="blue-div-1">
     <label>long text long text long text long text long text long text </label>
    </div>
</div>
   <br/>
<div class="green-div-2">
</div>
```

**else, you could add another element to cover the space in between:**

```css
.green-div-1{
  background-color:#00ba00; width:500px;height:20px;
}
.blue-div-1{
  background-color:#8888FF; max-width:90%; float:left;
}

.green-div-2{
  background-color:#00ba00; width:500px;height:20px;
}
.blue-div-1::after {
  content:"short text";
  display: block;
  background-color:#8888FF;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#space {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-div-1">
    <div class="blue-div-1">
     <label>long text long text long text long text long text long text </label>
    </div>
</div>
   <br/>
<div class="green-div-2">
</div>
<div id="space">

</div>
```